# GCC compiler error: unrecognized option '--export-dynamic'

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

The context is the following: I am trying to compile InkscapeLite from sources in Linux Mint. At the end of the compilation, the last command is (some .o and .a files are replaced with "`...`", because the command is very long):

`gcc -g -O2 -o inkscape --export-dynamic inkscape.o inkscape-stock.o ...  ./.libs/libinkscape.al dialogs/libspdialogs.a ... -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcairo.so -lpango-1.0 -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libart_lgpl_2.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpopt.so -lpng -lXft -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so -lz -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`

It fails with error: `gcc: error: unrecognized option '--export-dynamic'`

What I have done is to replace `--export-dynamic` with `-export-dynamic`, just for test (notice, I am not C/C++ programmer and know nothing about GCC or any other C compiler) and executed the command manually in the console. The compilation ended without errors and the program works, but it misses almost all toolbar and menu icons (only some common icons are there as open/save/copy/paste...)

Is it because of this problem option `--export-dynamic` or there is some different problem in the sources?

BTW, the same program works normally in the Puppy Linux distributions.

Comment: There is some problem elsewhere. It would only export more symbols than you need based on the dynamic linkage. This is good for potential debugging and/or dlopen/sym/close.

Comment: So, I have to remove `--export-dynamic` at all and search the problem elsewhere? Why `-export-dynamic` works then?

Comment: No, keep -expotr-dynamic, and keep looking for another issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the building scripts issue. `--export-dynamic` is a *linker* (`ld` in Unixes) option which could be useful in your case but it isn't gcc frontend option. All GCC versions I see have `-rdynamic` flag which causes passing of `--export-dynamic` to linker. So you can fix this with your own means (e.g. simply try to rename the option in makefile/etc.) and/or report the issue to maintainers.

Answer (score 4):

Use `gcc -rdynamic` or `-Wl,--export-dynamic` (the `-Wl` tells to send the next suboption to `ld` ...)